# Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Canary 1 Emulator Problem

Tags: android, android-studio

android emulator does not work in Android Studio Hedgehog version. It remains in the status shown on the screen below.

[image]

Even though I deleted all android emulators, the emulator above tries to open automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In the selected emulator winder, click the "close" icon and it will open the emulator then launch your app again. Weird though how the close action is gets rid of the "Loading" screen and shows the emulator. It's probably a bug